# Radio knob stuck help

Tags: cartridge

My radio knob was broken and they don’t sell new knobs have to buy whole radio so i gorilla glued it back on now it won’t move to turn on or do volume how can I get it loose

Comment: Need more info. Picture? What kind of radio?

Comment: And most importantly, what type of glue?

Comment: Urethane glue expands and foams as it cures. I quit using it for that reason. It's almost impossible not to make a mess. You need to cut, grind, or dissolve the errant glue. What more can be said?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because small appliance/gadget repair is off-topic on DIY.SE

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of glue. Gorilla is a brand that includes many types. The most common question tends to be with "super glue" and most of those have **acetone** (a.k.a. nail polish remover) as the usual antidote. But depending on other factors, that may not be so easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a blow dryer to heat it up so the glue softens.

Comment: For wood glue, white glue, etc. that will work well. For superglue, not so much.